# Линтер Flake8, игнорирование отдельных папок с файлами

Tags: visual-studio-code, linter, flake8

Установил себе линтер Flake8 в VSCode. Есть папка с основным проектом, где я бы хотел, чтобы работал линтер. Но также есть и другие папки с говно-кодами для теста функций, где линтер не нужен. Можно ли как то отключить flake8 для остальных папок, чтобы весь код не был в подчеркиваниях или включить его только для определенной папки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В корневой папке вашего проекта создайте файл с именем .flake8, если такого файла нет и добавьте туда конфигурацию

Пример файла .flake8:

```
[flake8]
exclude = tests/*
```

В данном примере, все файлы в папке tests будут исключены из линтинга